# How to make assembly loop repeated for user input number

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I try to make a code in assembly with loop but I'm new to this language and I can't find how to make it happen.

So the code I want to make is about the Fibonacci sequence.

**The problem is that I want the loop to be repeated for a number of the user input
(how many of the Fibonacci numbers he wants to be printed) but I cant find how to do it.**

Code is for x86 architecture.

Comment: in what architecture are you trying to write the assembler code?

Comment: oh yes sry i forgot.. **its x86 architercture**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my comprehension of your question isn't wrong, it asks "how to write a loop?"
So, here is a framework for basic loop  that iterates `n` times...
Let's say you have accepted `n` from the user and stored it into `-4(%ebp)`...

```
            movl    $0,    -8(%ebp)            # Let's say index i is at -8(%ebp)
            jmp condition                      # unconditional jump for entry-control loop.
for:                                           # Body of the loop
            # Your cool code here...

            addl    $1,    -8(%ebp)            # i++

condition:
            movl    -4(%ebp),    %eax          # Move n into eax
            cmpl    %eax,        -8(%ebp)      # Compare i with eax
            jl      for                        # if i < n jump to the label `for`
```

It is equivalent of the for the following for loop in C:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Your cool code here
}
```

If you want a do while like loop, you just have to remove the unconditional jump statement, so that it becomes an exit control loop.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touch x86 assembler for a long time but the following should work

```
label:

movl $3, %ecx  // put 3 into ecx register

// your code

decl %ecx      // decrement value in ecx register
jnz label      // loop back to label if ecx register is not zero
```

obviously you would store the number of your user's input in the ecx register instead of 3
also I'm assuming you already have the code to grab the user's input otherwise there needs to be a lot more assembler code